# Create Own Hardware To Locate Phones with GPSR receivers

Tags: mobile, geolocation, gps, location, hardware

I understand that phones use GPS receivers to communicate with gps satellites. I was wondering if it would be possible for me to create a piece of hardware to mimic a satellite signal to locate a phone?

Answer (score 0):

the phone does not communicate with the satellite, the gps receiver in the phone receives the signal from the gps satellite.  it is a one way thing.  And sure if you can generate the right signals the phone may see them but, the phone does not talk back to the gps satellite, it uses the phone network to communicate out which is a whole other thing

Comment: if you want to find a phone, the phone has to know where it is (gps or triangulation between towers, or other signals it can detect and choose between the strongest).  And then the phone needs software that you can communicate with.  And that software cant have protections to prevent you from communicating with it, and THEN you can write some software on some machine on the net that communicates.  If you want to take over a signal you would be looking at cdma or gsm or lte or other, not gps.  and still software is involved

Comment: did you mean GPSR or GPS in the title? and if GPSR which of the expansions of those letters did you intend?